# Thymeleaf doesn't see page html in templates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring boot application development. I use eclipse IDE, spring boot v.3.1.1, maven project.

The problem is that my `.html` pages are in templates (`src/main/resources/templates`), which need to be displayed by their link (like a localhost:8080/page), controllers were created for them. I also tried to display the page in case of an error (/error), which is located in the same folder - and it is displayed.

In addition, I will give the code of the main method, controllers, and a small code of the html pages (they are quite large ...)

`.java` file with void main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ChatSbAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChatSbAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Error controller (works fine):

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController implements org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Standard controllers:

```
@Controller
public class UserAccountController {

    private final UserAccountService userAccountService;

    @Autowired
    public UserAccountController(UserAccountService userAccountService) {
        this.userAccountService = userAccountService;
    }
    
    ///registration
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm() {
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUser(@RequestBody UserAccount userAccount) {
        userAccountService.saveUserAccount(userAccount);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
    
    ///authorisation
    
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginUser() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String processLoginForm() {
        return "redirect:/chats";
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ChatDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
server.error.whitelabel.enabled = false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

I also tried changing the config, but it didn't work either.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());
    }
}
```

HTML example below: error.html works, but same login.html does not see. Also thymeleaf saw fine .css/.js in /static...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Error Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{index.css}">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-logo">
        <button onclick="changeColor()" class="color-button">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex; margin-right: 40px;">
      <button class="auth-button" onclick="window.location.href='login.html'">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can also show the logs, but there is nothing surprising in them - not 1 error or warning, but not 1 mention of the created mapping (I read, in my opinion there should be a message, like "mapping was created along the path [x.html]" or something like that, I didn't have such a message). The thymeleaf dependency is also in pom.xml ;)

As I described above, I tried to change the thymeleaf config, but it didn't work. Also I read some other people's problems and tried to "Project->Update Maven Project" (Alt+F5) but it didn't help too

Comment: Hello, please check the package structure of your classes. It looks like the UserAccountController class is not found by Spring component scan. It should be in the same package as the main application class or in a sub-package of it.

Comment: Hi, class UserAccountController is in the folder src\main\java\com\lpchat\springboot\chatSbApp\controller, while the main class is 1 level up (src\main\java\com\lpchat\springboot\chatSbApp). ErrorController is located in the same folder as UserAccountControl.. and this is the most surprising thing, perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening link using window.location will require you to set complete path.

Try to replace

```
<button class="auth-button" onclick="window.location.href='login.html'">Login</button>
```

With

```
<button class="auth-button" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/login'">Login</button>
```

Also note you should not include .html extension since controller takes care of this when parsing templates